# One directive for multiple DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a web page containing two distinct zones.

In the first zone I'm drawing a force graph (*my-graph(data="datagr")*), when the user clicks on a node of this graph I'm trying to update the second zone (*{{datagr.info}}*).

Controller:

```
$scope.datagr = {nodes:nodes,links:links,info:"no info"};
```

HTML:

```
.row
  .col-xs-12
    {{datagr.info}}

...some code...

.col-sm-12.col-md-10
  my-graph(data="datagr")
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("appDirectives", []).directive("myGraph", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //values from controller
      var links = scope.data.links;
      var nodes = scope.data.nodes;

      ...some code...

      //add nodes
      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "node "+d.type+" "+d.status; })
        .on("click", function(d) {
          scope.data.info = d.type+" <br/> "+d.status;
          scope.$apply();
        })
        .call(force.drag);

    }
  };
});
```

When no html is inserted in *{{datagr.info}}* this is working fine.

What are my options to insert HTML in the second zone ?

Should I create another directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution without creating a new custom directive: ngBindHtml ( *Creates a binding that will innerHTML the result of evaluating the expression into the current element in a secure way.* )

Now instead of

```
.col-xs-12
  {{datagr.info}}
```

I have

```
.col-xs-12(ng-bind-html="datagr.info")
```

This solution depends on ngSanitize (angular-sanitize.js) an additional Angular module.

The question is still open to any other method.